# Changing the header color and size of my site

Tags: html

I'm trying to change the header of my website and change it from 650px to 150px and change the background color to white.

When I put in this code I get "unexpected RBRACE suggesting the ":" after "height" is incorrect.

```
#mainslider .slick-slide {
    background-color: #fff
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

First I deleted the background code and it said there was an unexpected error with the "{" then I added the background again, made it white, and now it is saying the ":" after "height" is wrong.

Comment: You're missing the semicolon (`;`) after `#fff`. It's not explicitly required for the *last* rule in a CSS selector, but it *is* required for all other rules.

Answer (score 1):

```
background-color: #fff;
height: 150px;
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the Semicolon(;) after the background-color. Also if mainslider is a class name then please put the Dot(.) before the mainslider.

```
mainslider .slick-slide {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```